# writing json-ish list to csv, line by line, in python for bitcoin addresses

Tags: python, json, csv, bitcoin

I'm querying the [onename api](https://api.onename.com/#lookup_users) in an effort to get the bitcoin addresses of all the users.

At the moment I'm getting all the user information as a json-esque list, and then piping the output to a file, it looks like this:

```
[{'0': {'owner_address': '1Q2Tv6f9vXbdoxRmGwNrHbjrrK4Hv6jCsz', 'zone_file': '{"avatar": {"url": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/kd4/111"}, "bitcoin": {"address": "1NmLvYVEZqPGeQNcgFS3DdghpoqaH4r5Xh"}, "cover": {"url": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/dx3/111"}, "facebook": {"proof": {"url": "https://facebook.com/jasondrake1978/posts/10152769170542776"}, "username": "jasondrake1978"}, "graph": {"url": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/grph/111"}, "location": {"formatted": "Mechanicsville, Va"}, "name": {"formatted": "Jason Drake"}, "twitter": {"username": "000001"}, "v": "0.2", "website": "http://1642.com"}', 'verifications': [{'proof_url': 'https://facebook.com/jasondrake1978/posts/10152769170542776', 'service': 'facebook', 'valid': False, 'identifier': 'jasondrake1978'}], 'profile': {'website': 'http://1642.com', 'cover': {'url': 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/dx3/111'}, 'facebook': {'proof': {'url': 'https://facebook.com/jasondrake1978/posts/10152769170542776'}, 'username': 'jasondrake1978'}, 'twitter': {'username': '000001'}, 'bitcoin': {'address': '1NmLvYVEZqPGeQNcgFS3DdghpoqaH4r5Xh'}, 'name': {'formatted': 'Jason Drake'}, 'graph': {'url': 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/grph/111'}, 'location': {'formatted': 'Mechanicsville, Va'}, 'avatar': {'url': 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/kd4/111'}, 'v': '0.2'}}}]
```

what I'm really interested in is the field `{"address": "1NmLvYVEZqPGeQNcgFS3DdghpoqaH4r5Xh"}`, the rest of the stuff I don't need, I just want the addresses of every user.

Is there a way that I can just write only the addresses to a file using python?

I'm trying to write it as something like:

```
1NmLvYVEZqPGeQNcgFS3DdghpoqaH4r5Xh,
1GA9RVZHuEE8zm4ooMTiqLicfnvymhzRVm,
1BJdMS9E5TUXxJcAvBriwvDoXmVeJfKiFV,
1NmLvYVEZqPGeQNcgFS3DdghpoqaH4r5Xh,
...
```

and so on.

I've tried a number of different ways using `dump`, `dumps`, etc. but I haven't yet been able to pin it down.

My code looks like this:

```
import os
import json
import requests
#import py2neo
import csv


# set up authentication parameters
#py2neo.authenticate("46.101.180.63:7474", "neo4j", "uni-bonn")

# Connect to graph and add constraints.
neo4jUrl = os.environ.get('NEO4J_URL',"http://46.101.180.63:7474/db/data/")
#graph = py2neo.Graph(neo4jUrl)

# Add uniqueness constraints.
#graph.run("CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (q:Person) ASSERT q.id IS UNIQUE;")

# Build URL.
apiUrl = "https://api.onename.com/v1/users"
# apiUrl = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/s-matthew-english/26.04/master/test.json"

# Send GET request.
Allusersjson = requests.get(apiUrl, headers = {"accept":"application/json"}).json()

#print(json)])
UsersDetails=[]
for username in Allusersjson['usernames']:
    usernamex= username[:-3]
    apiUrl2="https://api.onename.com/v1/users/"+usernamex+"?app-id=demo-app-id&app-secret=demo-app-secret"
    userinfo=requests.get(apiUrl2, headers = {"accept":"application/json"}).json()
    # try:
    #     if('bitcoin' not in userinfo[usernamex]['profile']):
    #         continue
    #     else:
    #         UsersDetails.append(userinfo)
    # except:
    #     continue
    try:
        address = userinfo[usernamex]["profile"]["bitcoin"]["address"]
        UsersDetails.append(address)
    except KeyError:
        pass  # no address

out = "\n".join(UsersDetails)
print(out)
open("out.csv", "w").write(out)

# f = csv.writer(open("test.csv", "wb+"))


# Build query.
query = """
RETURN {json}
"""

# Send Cypher query.
# py2neo.CypherQuery(graph, query).run(json=json)
# graph.run(query).run(json=json)

#graph.run(query,json=json)
```

anyway, in such a situation, what's the best way to write out those addresses as csv :/

---

**UPDATE**

I ran it, and at first it worked, but then I got the following error: 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding all the information to the UsersDetails list

```
UsersDetails.append(userinfo)
```

you can add just the relevant part (address)

```
try:
    address = userinfo[usernamex]["profile"]["bitcoin"]["address"]
    UsersDetails.append(address)
except KeyError:
    pass  # no address
except TypeError:
    pass  # illformed data
```

To print the values to the screen:

```
out = "\n".join(UsersDetails)  
print(out)
```

(replace "\n" with "," for comma separated output, instead of one per line)

To save to a file:

```
open("out.csv", "w").write(out)
```

Comment: I tried it out and it seemed to work but then I got an error which I snapped a picture of and added to the OP under the section **update**

Comment: It seems that JSON data is not consistent - there is a string where there should be a dictionary. Try adding an 'except TypeError: print userinfo' statement to debug the problem.

Comment: Also, I cannot comment on @Walid Mujahid's post, but putting a break statement there will do nothing.

Comment: but is there a way to just ignore those ill-formed ones?

Comment: ah cool- seems to work well :) is there a way to know periodically the progress of the execution? for instance- there are so many data points, and I'd like to know how many are left, so I can go do soemthing else and comfortably return to the program later- do you know what I mean? is there a way to do that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122580/discussion-between-mpurg-and-s-matthew-english).

Answer (score 1):

You need to reformat the list, either through `map()` or a list comprehension, to get it down to just the information you want.  For example, if the top-level key used in the response from the api.onename.com API is always `0`, you can do something like this

```
UsersAddresses = [user['0']['profile']['bitcoin']['address'] for user in UsersDetails]
```